# PER encoding of BIT STRING with named bits and extensible size constraint

Tags: asn.1

Given:

```
X ::= BIT STRING {a(0), b(1)} (SIZE(2, ...))
```

what is the correct length for the PER encoding to use for the value '00'B?

I argue that the encoding should use a length of 0, because X.691 16.3 calls for trimming to "the smallest size capable of carrying this value and satisfies the effective size constraint", and the constraint on X, by being extensible, allows for values having length 0.

However, "satisfies the effective size constraint" doesn't seem to be very well defined, and I know of tools that encode using a length of 2.

Nonetheless, even if the above phrase is not well defined, suppose we had:

```
X-V2 ::= BIT STRING {a(0), b(1)} (SIZE(2, ..., 0))
```

then I think it becomes hard to say, under any interpretation, that a length of 0 does not satisfy the effective size constraint.  That means for X-V2, '00'B would be encoded using a length of 0.  Furthermore, I believe in order to enable canonical PER encodings, X and X-V2 *must* encode '00'B in the same way, which means also using a length of 0 for '00'B for type X.

To my mind, the ambiguity arises from exactly what values are considered as making up, or being "present", in X, because X.691 gives these relevant definitions:

> 3.7.8 effective size constraint (for a constrained string type): A single finite size constraint that could be applied to a built-in string type and whose effect would be to permit all and only those lengths that *can be present* in the constrained string type.

> 10.3.10 The effective size constraint for a constrained type is a single size constraint such that a size is permitted if and only if *there is some value of the constrained type* that has that (permitted) size.

In a couple of places, X.680 leads us to believe that an extensible type consists of the values in the root plus any values in the extension additions:

Annex I 4.2.3 :

> ```
> A1 ::= INTEGER (1..32, ... , 33..128)
> ```
>
> A1 is extensible, and contains values 1 to 128 with 1 to 32 in the root and 33 to 128 as extension additions.

50.1:

> NOTE 6 – The elements that are referenced by "ElementSetSpecs" is the union of the elements referenced by the "RootElementSetSpec" and "AdditionalElementSetSpec" (when present).

But then it also seems to say that an extensible type contains all of the same values that are in the type being constrained:

6:

> In formal terms, an abstract syntax defined by the extensible type X contains not only the values of type X, but also the values of all types that are extension-related to X.

and 3.8.38:

> extension-related: Two types that have the same extension root, where one was created by adding zero or more extension additions to the other.

I think section 6 rules here and the language in Annex I 4.2.3 and in 50.1 note 6 is being imprecise.

**Update: Discussion of X.691 16.3 and 16.6**
Alessandro's answer (thanks for your input) applies 16.3 only after 16.6 is applied. Here's my interpretation of the relationship between the two.

First, 16.3 is an unqualified statement.  It does not say it applies only if the PER-visible constraint is not extensible, or, in the case where the constraint is extensible, only if the length of the BIT STRING falls inside the extension root of the constraint.  It also does not say anything that requires us to look at 16.6 to understand how to apply 16.3. It uses the phrase "effective size constraint", but that is a phrase that is elsewhere defined without depending on 16.6, although the definition is somewhat unclear, as I noted above. Apparently, though, an "effective size constraint" can be extensible because Annex B.3 has a IA5String example with an effective size constraint that is extensible:

```
A13 ::= IA5String (SIZE(1..10, ...) ^ FROM("A".."D"))
-- A13 has an extensible effective size constraint of SIZE(1..10,...)
```

Second, when 16.6 says "In the latter case the length and value shall be encoded as if no extension is present in the constraint." it does not say to go back to 16.1 and start over, or even to invoke 16.3 at that time.  Rather, I take this phrase to simply mean that we should act as if there were no extension marker as we continue on to the next point, 16.7, which says "If an extension marker is not present in the constraint specification of the bitstring type, then 16.8 to 16.11 apply." Indeed, 16.8 - 16.11 are concerned with how to encode the length, which means that the two branches of 16.6 both end up specifying how the length is encoded. That makes this a natural reading of 16.6.

Third, 16.6 requires us to take one of two branches depending on whether the "length of this encoding" is in the extension root or not.  The "length of this encoding" can only mean the "length of the string value" or the "length that is being used in the encoding".  It can't mean the "length that is being used in the encoding" unless 16.3 logically applies before 16.6.

Now, suppose we have

```
Y ::= BIT STRING {a(0), b(1)} (SIZE(0..4, ...))
```

and suppose that in 16.6 we are to understand "length of this encoding" to mean simply the "length of the string" and that 16.3 only applies when the length of the string is in the extension root.  Then, a Y of '11000'B is *not* trimmed (5 not in the root), but a Y of '1100'B *is* trimmed (to 2; 4 is in the root) - a result which seems somewhat odd (that one is trimmed but the longer one is not).

Moreover, for a Y value of '1100'B, in applying 16.6, we treated "the length of this encoding" as 4 (the length of the string) but then the length in the encoding is 2.  That seems a very strange use of English indeed!

It is 16.3 that creates the possibility that the length of the string and the length used in the encoding might not be equal.  When 16.6 then refers to the "length of this encoding", the natural reading is to assume that 16.3, which introduced the idea, logically precedes 16.6 and has therefore already been applied to determine the length that will be used in the encoding, which is what "length of this encoding" refers to.  The wording itself - length of this *encoding* - suggests this reading.

Under my interpretation, there are cases where a value is encoded as an extension value when it would seem more sensible to be encoded as a root value.  This happens whenever the root excludes values in the range 0..k because then the trimming can then result in a size shorter than what the root covers.  Nonetheless, I think that is what the spec calls for, on the most natural reading.  Personally, I think it is clear 16.3 logically precedes 16.6 and the ambiguity arises it what it means for a size to "satisfy" an "effective size constraint" in 16.3.  Does 0 "satisfy" an effective size constraint of SIZE(2, ...)?  I think we have to say it does; at least the spec is not clear that it doesn't, as far as I can see.

(End of update)

**Update 2: Counterarguments concerning 16.3 and 16.6**
First, as Alessandro notes, 17.3 (for octet strings) and 20.4 (for sequence of) parallel 16.6 and the one refers to the "length of this encoding" while the other refers to the "number of components in this encoding", both of which really just refer to the length or to the number of components of the value.  This gives us reason to think 16.6 also refers to just the length of the value when it says "length of this encoding".  If it weren't for 16.3, they would be one in the same, but given 16.3, there is the potential for confusion.  Still, this might just be an unintentional and unfortunate choice of words, and it could be they meant to refer to the length of original value.

Second, it is pretty clear that when 16.6 requires encoding "as if no extension is present in the constraint", this applies not just to the following clauses but also to a prior clause, namely 16.4, since, otherwise, extensible types would never use an optimized encoding for the length (ub would be unset in such cases).  So, if the "as if" applies to one clause before 16.6, then why not to another clause, namely 16.3?  Then for type X, '00'B has length of 2, which is in the root, so according to 16.6 we encode it as if the extension weren't present.  That means 16.3 does not trim the string, as the effective size constraint is then SIZE(2), not SIZE(2, ...).

This interpretation raises a new question: what about an X of '1110'B?  The length is not in the extension root, so 16.6 does not have us encode it as if the extension were not present and, supposedly, 16.3 does not apply (though it is not absolutely clear that 16.3 only applies to "root" values).  Thus, X.691 does not clearly require trimming the trailing zero bit in this case.  However, Paul Thorpe argues it should be trimmed nonetheless.  After all, X.680 22.7 tells us that '1110'B and '111'B should be treated (by application designers) as having the same semantics, and encoding rules can arbitrarily add or remove trailing bits.  Therefore, some encoding rules *could* encode '1110'B using the exact same bits as for '111'B.  However, this doesn't mean that all encoding rules *must* do so, nor does it dictate that PER, in particular, *must* do so.  Still, it does mean that if a PER implementation trims '1110'B to '111'B when encoding, a user at least can't complain they got back an unepxected value of '111'B after decoding.  However, this doesn't answer what the correct encoding is, and there must be a single correct encoding if we're to have canonical encodings.

A similar question as for '1110'B arises for an X of '1100'B.  The length is 4, which length is not in the root, but it is semantically equivalent to '11'B, whose length is in the root.  It seems not unreasonable to encode '1100'B the same as '11'B, but the specs don't make it absolutely clear that this is what PER requires.  Similarly for an X of ''B, with a length of 0, which length is not in the root, but it is also semantically equivalent to '00'B, which, under this alternative interpretation, should be encoded as length 2.

IMO, ITU-T needs to make some clarifications here as I don't think the arguments one way or the other are decisive.  I believe the specification is inherently vague.

(End of update 2)

Basically, I'm looking for a contrary argument or for someone to point out what I've missed, if I have missed something.

Comment: Do you want to know for curiosity, or do you really want to trim 2 bits from your data? Because it doesn't seem worth worrying about the 2 bits if you have something that works.

Comment: @JohnBayko I want to know for correctness.  It's not supposed to be an encoder's option, whether to encode using a length of 0 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is contradicted by clause 16.6, which deals with types extensible for PER encodings (especially the last phrase, "encoded as if no extension is present"). I believe clauses 16.1 to 16.5 refer to types that are not extensible for PER encodings, or to the cases in which the length and value are to be "encoded as if no extension is present" in accordance with 16.6. This also implies that the phrase "effective size constraint" in 16.3 is to be understood as referring to
the root part of it.

Comment: Applying 16.6, the type is extensible for PER encodings, so the next question is whether the "length of the encoding" is "within the range of the extension root".  Note it is the length of the *encoding* not the length of the *value* that is in question.  We have to apply 16.3 to determine the length of the encoding.  If the encoding length is 0 (not in the extension root), then 16.6 specifies an extension bit of 1; if it is 2, then the extension bit will be 0.  So, I don't think 16.6 contradicts my interpretation.  Rather, the correct application of 16.6 depends on how 16.3 is understood.

Comment: Please note that you are dealing with a BIT STRING with a NamedBitList.  The encoder is permitted to add or remove bits to comply with the size constraint.  If no bits are set, the length should still be 2 bits to comply with the size constraint for the extension root.

Comment: Clause 16.6 says, "In the latter case the length and value shall be encoded as if no extension is present in the constraint", which also applies to the phrase "satisfies the effective size constraint" in 16.3. That is, the reference to the "effective size constraint" in 16.3 should be understood as the root part of the effective size constraint because 16.6 says that the encoding must be as if no extension is present in the constraint.  Clause 16.6 cannot depend on 16.3, otherwise it would be self-contradictory.

Comment: A further consideration is that if a value can be understood as being a root value (thanks to clause 16.3 allowing the addition or removal of trailing zero bits), then it should be encoded as a root value.

Comment: @PaulThorpe Maybe you can create an answer that cites the spec as to why the length should be a length that is in the extension root, versus zero, because I wasn't able to do so myself.  After all, strings of length zero are allowed, thanks to the extensibility.

Comment: @Alessandro Thanks for your input.  I updated the question with a discussion of 16.6 and 16.3.

Comment: Clause 16 has the same structure as clauses 17 (octetstring types) and 20 (sequence-of types). These clauses start dealing with the types not extensible for PER, then they address the types extensible for PER. Subclauses 16.6, 17.3, and 20.4 are identical.  If you had to take account of the presence of the extension marker when applying 16.2-16.4, then "ub" would have to be infinite in your case, and you would never get a root encoding.

Comment: @Alessandro That's not quite true, because ub doesn't control whether you get a root or extended encoding; it only comes into play when you get to 16.8 and following.  But, I do go back to and reapply 16.4 for root value case as if the extension marker were not there.  And 17.3 also says "length of this encoding", so maybe it's just a bad choice of words.  In 17 there's no possible difference between length of the value and length used in the encoding.  16 creates that possibility by 16.3 which creates the potention for confusion.  Hmmm....

Comment: By "root encoding" I meant the kind of finite-lengh encoding, typical of PER, that you get for root values when there is a finite and small "ub". Sorry for the sloppy language. Anyway, if you do go back and reapply 16.4 for the root value case as if the extension marker were not there, you should do the same with regard to the effective size constraint in 16.3. Indeed my point is that one should start with 16.6.

Comment: @Kevin Please notice Rec. ITU-T X.691 | ISO/IEC 8825-2 clause 10.4.3 which is as follows: 10.4.3 When a constraint includes a value as an extension addition that is present in the root, that value is always encoded as a value in the root, not as a value which is an extension addition.

Comment: @PaulThorpe  I don't believe 10.4.3 applies.  See my comment on your answer.

Comment: @Alessandro So, what do you say about the empty bit string, ''B, encoding for type X?  It's length is not in the root so under your interpretation, 16.3 doesn't apply and it will be encoded as length 0 and no zero bits will be added?  Actually, if 16.3 applies only when the length of the BIT STRING value is in the root of the constraint, then when would zero bits ever be *added*, as anticipated by 16.3?  You'd only add bits when the length is shorter than what the root allows and therefore not in the root.

Comment: @Kevin You are dealing with a BIT STRING with a NamedBitList. Please notice Rec. ITU-T X.680 | ISO/IEC 8824-1 clause 22.7 which is as follows: 22.7 When a "NamedBitList" is used in defining a bitstring type ASN.1 encoding rules are free to add (or remove) arbitrarily any trailing 0 bits to (or from) values that are being encoded or decoded. Application designers should therefore ensure that different semantics are not associated with such values which differ only in the number of trailing 0 bits. This means that a bitstring value with no bits set is in the root.

Comment: 1/2 If one looks back at clause 11.2.2 of X.690 (DER encoding of a bitstring type with named bits), one must infer that in ASN.1 as a whole, trailing zero bits have no significance for a bitstring type with named bits. The very fact that any two values that differ only in the number of trailing zero bits are indistiguishable after being encoded in DER, implies that those two values are to be treated in any use of ASN.1, regardless of the encoding rules, as if they were the same value. Clause 16.3 of X.691 confirms this conclusion.

Comment: 2/2 The encoding of a value in PER (for a bitstring with named bits) cannot depend on the number of trailing zero bits that happen to be present in the value passed to the encoder. In the application of 16.6, one should first determine if the value can be understood as a root value by adding or removing trailing zero bits, and only then decide if it's a root value or an extension addition value.

Comment: @PaulThorpe X.680 22.7 does not alter which values are in the root.  It only gives permission to encoding rules to add/remove trailing zero bits.  But if it is true that ''B is in the root, then when I come to 16.3, how do I escape transmitting the value as ''B, as that must satisfy the effective size constraint and there is nothing shorter than that?

Comment: @Kevin X.680 22.7 clearly indicates the abstract value consists of which bits are set in the bit string and does not take into account the length of the bit string.  No semantics should be associated with the addition or removal of trailing zero bits.

Comment: @PaulThorpe  No, it doesn't.  If 22.7 means that '100' and '10000' are in fact the same abstract value, it would say that.  The very notion of assigning "different semantics" to "such values" implies you have distinct values to assign semantics to.  Rather, 22.7 is a caution to application designers based on what encoding rules *may* do.  It does not say anything about how ASN.1 treats those values (other than granting the encoding rules a certain permission).

Comment: For BIT STRING X with named bits and SIZE(2, ...), your argument is that ''B and '0000'B should be treated as '00'B (though nothing explicitly says to coerce the value into a root value, if possible, before applying 16.6, which almost eliminates the need for 16.3) and then 16.6 should be applied (where the length is in root), and then 16.3 applied (no adjustment required now).  What about '1110'B and '11100'B?  Is the encoding the same for these values, or different?  Trimming them won't coerce them into a root value and no other rule indicates they should be trimmed (unless 16.3 applies).

Comment: @Kevin The fact that the definition has a NamedBitList means that '1110'B and '11100'B are the same abstract value.  The PER encoding rules do specify that the encodings for these should be the same since trailing zero bits should be removed from the encoding.  Since these are outside of the size constraint, the extension bit should be set, but the trailing zero bits should still be removed.

Comment: @PaulThorpe  Are you saying that by 16.3 the trailing bits should be trimmed in that case (@Alessandro disagrees) or by some other unstated rule?  As I noted above, I disagree that '1110'B and '11100'B are the same abstract value but I agree application designers (which doesn't mean ASN.1 implementers!) should treat them as having the same semantic meaning.  Do you agree the spec is not really clear on how to deal with BIT STRING with named bits and extensible size constraint?

Comment: @Kevin Even though X.680 does not literally state that bitstring values with named bits that differ only for trailing zeros are the same abstract value, there is clear normative text in X.680, X.690, and X.691 that causes such values to be indistinguishable after an encoding/decoding cycle.  Whether you call them "the same" abstract value or "two indistinguishable" abstract values, is a detail of the terminology. To all practical effects, the PER encoder must behave as if it stripped the trailing zeros and then proceed with 16.6.

Comment: So, the next step is to determine whether ''B, in your example, is a root value or an extension addition. Since ''B can be understood either as a root value ('00'B which has the same meaning as ''B satisfies the size constraint), or an extension addition, it must be encoded as a root value.

Comment: @Kevin No I do not agree that the spec is not clear on how to deal BIT STRING with a NamedBitList when an extensible size constraint is present.  The overarching principle is that when a NamedBitList is present, trailing zero bits are not to be used to distinguish between two values (or two encodings).

Comment: @PaulThorpe  Okay, so I think our difference boils down to what counts as a root value from a BIT STRING with named bits and an extensible size constraint.  I don't believe X.680 22.7 clearly answers the question, because it merely gives permission to encoding rule definitions to add/trim zeros and a warning to application designers.  It doesn't alter the definition of what is or is not a root value.  I think it would be great for ITU-T to clarify so there can be no question, in X.691 16.6 over the meaning of "the length of this encoding is not within the range of the extension root".

Comment: @PaulThorpe  Also, I think ITU-T should clarify the handling of trailing zero bits for values that are *not* within the extension root, i.e. if the size constraint is SIZE(2, ...), does '1110000' get the trailing zeros trimmed?  Alessandro argues 16.3 doesn't apply in such a case, and you claimed the zeros should be trimmed in such a case, but X.690 certainly doesn't clearly call for the trimming (if 16.3 doesn't apply) and X.680 22.7 gives encoding rules *permission* to trim trailing zeros, but it doesn't *require* them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice Rec. ITU-T X.691 | ISO/IEC 8825-2 clause 10.4.3 which is as follows:

10.4.3 When a constraint includes a value as an extension addition that is present in the root, that value is always encoded as a value in the root, not as a value which is an extension addition.

You then should use clause 16.3 which states the following:

16.3    Where there is a PER visible constraint and Rec. ITU-T X.680 | ISO/IEC 8824-1, 22.7, applies (i.e. the bitstring type is defined with a "NamedBitList"), the value shall be encoded with trailing 0 bits added or removed as necessary to ensure that the size of the transmitted value is the smallest size capable of carrying this value and satisfies the effective size constraint.

The encoding should be one with 2 zero bitstring bits to satisfy the size constraint.

Please also notice Rec. ITU-T X.680 | ISO/IEC 8824-1 clause 22.7 which reads as follows:

22.7    When a "NamedBitList" is used in defining a bitstring type ASN.1 encoding rules are free to add (or remove) arbitrarily any trailing 0 bits to (or from) values that are being encoded or decoded. Application designers should therefore ensure that different semantics are not associated with such values which differ only in the number of trailing 0 bits.

Comment: 10.4.3 does not apply to this case.  It covers the case where an extension addition value is present in the root, and it gives an example of such a case: INTEGER (0..10, ..., 5).  But, that is not the situation in question.  The size constraint is SIZE(2, ...) and the length of 0 is not in the root.

Comment: @Kevin You are dealing with a BIT STRING with a NamedBitList.  Please notice Rec. ITU-T X.680 | ISO/IEC 8824-1 clause 22.7 which is as follows:  
22.7 When a "NamedBitList" is used in defining a bitstring type ASN.1 encoding rules are free to add (or remove) arbitrarily any trailing 0 bits to (or from) values that are being encoded or decoded. Application designers should therefore ensure that different semantics are not associated with such values which differ only in the number of trailing 0 bits.

This means that a bitstring value with no bits set is in the root.